# Filing business taxes with just a social security number?

Tags: business, tax-law

I read this:

> Every business that pays employees **or is required to file any business tax returns** is required to obtain an EIN.

Source: https://justworks.com/blog/itin-ssn-or-ein-whats-the-difference

Is this true? I am a sole proprietor and have filed business taxes on a Form 1040 with just a social security number.  I did not obtain an EIN, nor did anyone say I had to, when I did business taxes.

I always just use SSN. Is it illegal to file business taxes as a sole proprietor with just an SSN?

Comment: I read "business tax return" as "tax return in the name of the business".  When the business is a sole proprietorship, the business itself doesn't have to file a tax return.  Rather, you include the income and expenses of the business in your personal income tax return.  So even in light of feetwet's answer, I don't think the statement is false, just perhaps not stated very clearly.

Comment: Businesses don't file tax returns, corporations do. A sole proprietorship is a business without a corporation. Yes, okay, this is a huge oversimplification, and there are exceptions, but that's the underlying principle. Form 1040 is a personal income tax return, where you report personal business income.

Answer (score 1):

As you have experienced, you are not "required" to obtain an EIN to file "any" business tax returns.  You can go as far as a sole proprietorship filing on Schedule C just using your personal SSN.

You don't need an EIN until you either pay employees or want to file taxes as a separate business entity (e.g., an LLC).

Comment: Actually, even in the case of an LLC, it is a disregarded entity and you can file on Schedule C if you have just one owner of the LLC and don't affirmatively elect to be taxed as a corporation.

Comment: @ohwilleke and if you make that election, the LLC needs an EIN, correct?

Comment: @phoog yes, because the corporation will then constitute a "real" (as opposed to "disregarded") entity and have to make filings as such.  (And the only taxpayer identification number available to a filer that is not a natural person is an EIN.)